# PostgreSQL to DataFrame loop, for my Dash app, is not working as intended

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, dataframe

I'm trying create one DataFrame for my Dash app. The dataframe consists of Stock Market data taken from my SQL dB. `symbols` is a list of stocks inputted by the user, for this post I gave a few examples.

UPDATE:
With the help of @Parfait, this is the code I'm using, but it still doesn't seem to work even after overcoming previous bugs/errors.

```
@app.callback(
dash.dependencies.Output('table_stats', 'data'),
[dash.dependencies.Input('dynamic-dropdown', 'value')])


def statsTable(symbols):
    if symbols == None:
        raise PreventUpdate
    
    placeholders = ", ".join(['%s' for _ in symbols])
    
    # PREPARED STATEMENT WITH PARAM PLACEHOLDERS
    sql = f"""SELECT id, companyname, marketcap
                     , to_char(100.0*week52change,'999D99%'), week52high, week52low
                     , to_char(dividend_yield * 100, '99D99%'), next_earnings_date
                     , pe_ratio, ROUND(beta,2) 
              FROM security_stats 
              WHERE security_stats.id IN ({placeholders})
           """

    print(sql)
    final_df = postgresql_to_dataframe_v1(conn, sql, symbols, stats_col)

    

 

    return dt.DataTable(data=final_df.to_dict('rows'), columns=stats_col)
```

Here is my new postgresql_to_dataframe_v1() function:

```
def postgresql_to_dataframe_v1(conn, select_query, param, column_names):
    """
    Tranform a SELECT query into a pandas dataframe
    """
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(select_query, param)             # ADJUSTED LINE
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(f"Error: {error}")                          # MODERNIZED STRING FORMAT
        cursor.close()
        return 1
    
    # Naturally we get a list of tupples
    tupples = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    
    # We just need to turn it into a pandas dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(tupples, columns=column_names)
    return df
```

I now have this error: "List index out of range", which I think it has to do with the parameter passed or symbols because the data does not get pulled correctly, the error comes from within the function.

this is the message I get in my terminal, note that I use `print(symbols)` and `print(sql)` at the start of the function, which is why you see ['VFC', 'EXPD', 'COG', 'O'] and the SQL query in the terminal.

[image: terminal output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you are using an unquoted string literal. Postgres reads your query as the following where the `fb` entity is assumed to be a column identifier.

```sql
SELECT id, companyname, marketcap
      , to_char(100.0*week52change,'999D99%'), week52high, week52low
      , to_char(dividend_yield * 100, '99D99%'), next_earnings_date
      , pe_ratio, ROUND(beta,2) 
FROM security_stats 
WHERE security_stats.id = fb   -- should be 'fb'
```

However, don't just add single quotes into your Python F-string. Consider [parameterization](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) especially if users define stock tickers (else a clever, malicious user can [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) you!). Specifically, add a new parameter to function and pass `stock` variable into it via loop.

```py
def postgresql_to_dataframe(conn, select_query, param, column_names):
    """
    Tranform a SELECT query into a pandas dataframe
    """
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(select_query, [param])      # ADJUSTED LINE IF param IS SCALAR
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(f"Error: {error}")                   # MODERNIZED STRING FORMAT
        cursor.close()
        return 1
    
    # Naturally we get a list of tupples
    tupples = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    
    # We just need to turn it into a pandas dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(tupples, columns=column_names)
    return df


for stock in symbols:
    # PREPARED STATEMENT WITH PARAM PLACEHOLDER
    sql = """SELECT id, companyname, marketcap
                     , to_char(100.0*week52change,'999D99%%'), week52high, week52low
                     , to_char(dividend_yield * 100, '99D99%%'), next_earnings_date
                     , pe_ratio, ROUND(beta,2) 
             FROM security_stats 
             WHERE security_stats.id = %s
          """

    df = postgresql_to_dataframe(conn, sql, stock, col)
    df.head()
```

---

And for a fully compiled data frame using your function, build a list of data frames and concatenate.

```py
df_list = [postgresql_to_dataframe(conn, sql, stock, col) for stock in symbols]

final_df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

---

But it would be better to use a `IN` clause for a single SQL query call. Note below F-string is used only to interpolate the `%s` placeholders to SQL statement but later binds `symbols` via parameterization.

```py
placeholders = ", ".join(['%s' for _ in symbols])

# PREPARED STATEMENT WITH PARAM PLACEHOLDERS
sql = f"""SELECT id, companyname, marketcap
                 , to_char(100.0*week52change,'999D99%%'), week52high, week52low
                 , to_char(dividend_yield * 100, '99D99%%'), next_earnings_date
                 , pe_ratio, ROUND(beta,2) 
          FROM security_stats 
          WHERE security_stats.id IN ({placeholders})
       """

final_df = postgresql_to_dataframe(conn, sql, symbols, col)

# ALTERNATIVELY, WITH PANDAS METHODS
final_df = (pd.read_sql(sql, conn, params=symbols)
              .reindex(col, axis='columns'))
```

Comment: Making a new comment to replace my old one as I didn't see you make an edit. Your suggestion is working to an extent, I still seem to get an error, the function `postgresql_to_dataframe()` is returning a digit which means there was an error somewhere. Do you know where that might be? I'm getting an `Error: list index out of  range`.

Comment: Whoops! Parameters should be passed in `cursor.execute` as a collection (tuple, list, dict). See edit and try again.

Comment: Hey @Parfait, I made that edit. Still getting the same error as before. (I've also updated the original post with your new edits and corrections so others could potentially help. It must be something going wrong with the Query because I'm still getting a "1" from my sql-to-df function. Would you appear to know why? Maybe we need to put it in a loop form and iterate over every value in the `symbols` list?

Comment: I should have asked which version you were using (i.e., looped version or single version with `IN`). Since `symbols` is itself a list, do not use `[param]` but only `param` in `cursor.execute`. This would differ with looped version which passes a scalar value into method. See edited comment in code, `# ADJUSTED LINE IF param IS SCALAR`. Other than than, try printing out the SQL and count `%s` in query and see if it matches with length of `symbols`. Both should match in count.

Comment: So I'm using your single method, sorry for the mix-up. Your right the symbol length matches the `%s` count. I'm still getting a list index out of range however, the function is still buggy. So weird I thought it would work by now...

Comment: So did you change `[param]` to `param` in `cursor.execute`? Your post does not reflect change. How is `symbols` being passed into function? Please show an example assignment of `symbols` and example call to `statsTable()`?

Comment: Yes I remove the brackets around `param`, I just now updated my post to reflect that. symbols is being passed using the Dash `@callback` method. When I `print(symbols)`.  Please review my updated post for more information that may help.

Comment: Just noticed elsewhere in query you use `%` which is a special symbol with parameterized queries. Try doubling them up to escape `'999D99%%'`.

Comment: Thank you so much, the single percent signs were the issue. My function works as intended now. You made the start to my weekend! One last error I'm getting, `Invalid argument `data` passed into DataTable with ID "table_stats".
Expected an array.
Was supplied type `object`.`  I Guess I need to turn my dictionary into a list of dictionaries?

Comment: Sounds good! Glad to help. Error appears to be related to dash and I see you asked a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63964534/1422451). Hopefully you get an answer.